# Calculate $\theta$ from recurrence function $T(n)=8T(\frac{n}{2})+n^2$

Tags: asymptotics, recursion

How to properly calculate $\Theta$ of recurrence function $T(n)=8T(\frac{n}{2})+n^2$ ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you’re asking?

Comment: Please see the advice [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Using [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)):
$$T(n) = \Theta(n^3)$$